# branch of logarithm of $z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's one of the recommended exercises from our complex analysis class.

> Prove or disprove: There is no analytic $f$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus 0$ such that $exp(f(z)) = z^2$ for all nonzero $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Via differentiating both sides of the equation, I get $f'(z) = \frac{2}{z}$. Integrating along the unit disk, $\int_{\partial B(0,1)} f'(z) = 0$.

Am I right in that my hunch is that there is no such $f$? To show this, I think I must show that this integral is non-zero. How do I do this?

Comment: When you integrate $2/z$ around a circle containing the origin, you don't get zero.

Comment: That is what I want to show, that it can't be 0 around the unit circle, contradicting my earlier calculation that it is 0.

Won't the integral of 2/z along any closed curve in the domain be zero since 2/z has an antiderivative in the domain?

Comment: The antiderivative of $2/z$ is $2\log z$, which can't be defined in a neighborhood of zero.

Answer (score 2):

Just like there is no $\log$ on this domain.

As you said $f'(z)=2/z$.

Hence, integrating along the unit circle,
$$
\int_\mathbb{T} f'(z)dz=2\int_\mathbb{T}\frac{dz}{z}.
$$

Now the lhs yields
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}f'(e^{i\theta})ie^{i\theta}d\theta=f(e^{2\pi i})-f(e^{\cdot 0i})=f(1)-f(1)=0
$$
while the rhs is
$$
2\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ire^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}}d\theta=4i\pi.
$$
Contradiction.